# Postfix! Sending mail from outside

Tags: postfix

My server running ubuntu server 10.04 with postfix dovecot(IMAP,IMAPs) PAM-LDAP(opends).

My company user want to check and send mail from their own thunderbird in their own laptop, at this time my server only provide checking and sending locally,,,they must login to the webmail when they are from outside of company. They can checking email from outside but they can not sending .. the error is relay access denied !

My question is how to confiugre the mail server for authenticated user can send and receive both from inside and outside via email client software like Thunderbird/Evolution.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
     check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/maps/access-allowed-outside-senders,
     reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
     reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
     reject_unauth_pipelining,
     permit_mynetworks,
     reject_unauth_destination,
     reject

/etc/postfix/maps/access-allowed-outside-senders:
    allowed_user@yourdomain.net  OK

This way, allowed_user@yourdomain.net is allowed to send mail outside of your domain, even if he is outside of your network.

Answer (score 2):

You should configure SMTP AUTH.
Read [this](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_dovecot), you can start from there.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,,,My mail user can authenticate via port 993 but I got the problem when they send email, may be I will reconfigure mail server for outgoing mail via port 465